# How can I emulate Microsoft Excel's Solver functionality (GRG Nonlinear) in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, non-linear-regression

Screenshot demonstrating the use of Excel's Solver:

[image: See Screenshot demonstrating the use of Excel's Solver]

I have a task to automate a certain excel worksheet. The worksheet happens to implement a logic with an excel plugin called Solver. It uses a single value(-1.95624) in Cell $O$9 (which is the result of computations highlighted with red and blue ink in the diagram ) as an input value and then returns three values for C, B1 and B2 using an algorithm called "GRG Non linear regression". My task is to emulate this logic in Python. Below is my attempt. The major problem, is I am not getting the same values for C, B1 and B2 as computed by Excel's Solver plugin.

Given these datasets for xData and yData, the correct output should be:
C= -2.35443383, B1 = -14.70820051, B2 = 0.0056217

Here's My 1st Attempt:

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

xData = numpy.array([-2.59772914040242,-2.28665528866907,-2.29176070881848,-2.31163972446061,-2.28369414349715,-2.27911303233721,-2.28222332344644,-2.39089535619106,-2.32144325648778,-2.17235002006179,-2.22906032068685,-2.42044014499938,-2.71639505549322,-2.65462061336346,-2.47330475191616,-2.33132910807216,-2.33025978869114,-2.61175064230516,-2.92916553244925,-2.987503044973,-3.00367414706232,-1.45507812104723])  # Use the same table name as the parameter
yData = numpy.array([0.0692847120775066,0.0922342111029099,0.0918076382491768,0.0901635409944003,0.0924824386284127,0.092867647175396,0.092605957740688,20.0838696111204451,0.0893625419994501,0.102261091024881,0.097171046758256,70.0816272542472914,0.0620128251290935,0.0657047909578125,0.0777509345715382,0.088561321341585,0.088647672874835,90.0683859871424735,0.0507304952495273,0.0479936476914665,0.0472601632188253,0.18922126828463])  # Use the same table name as the parameter

def func(x, a, b, Offset): # Sigmoid A With Offset from zunzun.com
    return  1.0 / (1.0 + numpy.exp(-a * (x-b))) + Offset


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxY]) # search bounds for Offset

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# generate initial parameter values
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# curve fit the test data
params, covariance = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters,maxfev=50000)  

# Convert parameters to Python built-in types
params = [float(param) for param in params]  # Convert numpy float64 to Python float
C, B1, B2 = params
OutputDataSet = pd.DataFrame({"C": [C], "B1": [B1], "B2": [B2],"ProType":[input_value_1],"RegType":[input_value_2]})
```

Any Ideas will be helpful? Thanks in advance

Here's My 2nd Attempt: I've changed the objective function.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Access input data passed from SQL Server
datasets = pd.DataFrame(InputDataSet)



def logistic_regression(x, C, B1, B2):
    return C / (1 + np.exp(-B1 * (x - B2)))

def initial_coefficients(num_features):
    return np.random.randn(num_features)


# Fetch x_data and y_data from SQL Server           
x_data = np.array([-2.59772914040242,-2.28665528866907,-2.29176070881848,-2.31163972446061,-2.28369414349715,-2.27911303233721,-2.28222332344644,-2.39089535619106,-2.32144325648778,-2.17235002006179,-2.22906032068685,-2.42044014499938,-2.71639505549322,-2.65462061336346,-2.47330475191616,-2.33132910807216,-2.33025978869114,-2.61175064230516,-2.92916553244925,-2.987503044973,-3.00367414706232,-1.45507812104723])

y_data = np.array([0.0692847120775066,0.0922342111029099,0.0918076382491768,0.0901635409944003,0.0924824386284127,0.092867647175396,0.092605957740688,20.0838696111204451,0.0893625419994501,0.102261091024881,0.097171046758256,70.0816272542472914,0.0620128251290935,0.0657047909578125,0.0777509345715382,0.088561321341585,0.088647672874835,90.0683859871424735,0.0507304952495273,0.0479936476914665,0.0472601632188253,0.18922126828463])

initial_guess = initial_coefficients(3); # Example initial guess    
# Fit the logistic regression function to the data
params, covariance = curve_fit(logistic_regression, x_data, y_data, p0=initial_guess, maxfev=5000)
    

# Convert parameters to Python built-in types
params = [float(param) for param in params]  # Convert numpy float64 to Python float
C, B1, B2 = params
OutputDataSet = pd.DataFrame({"C": [C], "B1": [B1], "B2": [B2],"ProType":[input_value_1],"RegType":[input_value_2]})
```

But still didn't hit the desired result of
C= -2.35443383, B1 = -14.70820051, B2 = 0.0056217

Comment: You've made an admirable effort, but the objective function should be different -- should be cross entropy instead of sum of squares -- and you should use a gradient based minimization. Also, in all likelihood there is already an implementation of logistic regression in numpy or another library so you don't need to sort it out. My advice is to look for an existing implementation of LR -- there are probably several to choose from. Also, you can do an end-run around the whole question of minimization by assuming two Gaussian blobs with the same covariance. Let me know if you want to try that.

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestions. But I'd appreciate an actual edits or refactoring of the code. As I am fairly new to some of these concepts. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, to be more specific, my advice is to use an existing Python library for logistic regression, and it looks like the most obvious (but not the only one) is scikit-learn. See [the documentation for scikit-learn's LR model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). [This tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/understanding-logistic-regression-python) makes use of scikit-learn's LR, while [this other tutorial](https://library.virginia.edu/data/articles/logistic-regression-four-ways-with-python) mentions that one and three others.